# SSIS Year() function incorrect for end of year?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

In my OLE DB Source, I have a query that uses a parameter:

```
AND x.plan_year = YEAR(?)
```

The parameter is a date value, set to a variable I control. For most dates this returns the correct database values, but I noticed that 12/30/2012 and 12/31/2012 were evaluating to "2013". Has anyone seen this before? It doesn't happen if I use the YEAR function in a derived column or anything, just this specific scenario. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: is that variable evaluated by an expression? If yes, double check your expression, to see you are not adding a couple of days to it.

Comment: No, I'm just setting it by hand and running this particular task to see what it returns.

Comment: Where exactly do you see it evaluating to 2013? The code snippet you showed seems to be part of a query, so is `YEAR()` a SQL function being executed on the OLE DB source or an SSIS function being executed in the package? If it's a SQL query, it would be good to know what the OLE DB source is (SQL Server?), what the full query looks like, what SSIS data type the variable is (string?), and what the variable's actual value is ("12/31/2012"?).

Comment: What is the rest of the query?  What is the value of @@datefirst?